# Browser Detection on iOS

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, safari, user-agent

I currently struggle with browser detection on mobile apple devices. I tested safari, chrome and firefox on the very same device and the results make it very difficult for me to detect the exact browser. Have a look:

**Safari**

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) Apple WebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari 604/1

os=mac; browser=safari; device=iphone; os_version=unknown; browser_version=12.1

**Chrome (Desktop view)**

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) Apple WebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.1 Safari/605.1.15

os=mac; browser=safari; device=unknown; os_version="mac-os-x-13"; browser_version=11.1.1

**Chrome (Mobile view)**

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) Apple WebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOs/77.0.3865.103 Mobile/15E148 Safari 605/1

os=mac; browser=chrome; device=iphone; os_version=unknown; browser_version=77.0.3865.103

**Firefox (Desktop view)**

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) Apple WebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15

os=mac; browser=safari; device=unknown; os_version="mac-os-x-13"; browser_version=12.0

**Firefox (Mobile view)**

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) Apple WebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/19.1b16203 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1.15

os=mac; browser=safari; device=iphone; os_version=unknown; browser_version=0

The first line is the useragent string, the other details come from a lib I am using. As you may see it is very difficult to detect the correct device from this details. As a result I want to allow only safari on mobile iOS devices, but most of the other versions also mask themselves as safari.

Is there a best practice for browser detection? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just decided to go with this regular expression:
https://coderwall.com/p/ktrbhq/detect-mobile-safari

Anyway, I don't like this solution. A better approach is much appreciated.